# "sudo -i", "sudo su" and "su" commands not working - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, authentication

When running `sudo -i` i get `sudo: 5.8: command not found`, `sudo su` outputs `su: failed to execute 5.8: No such file or directory` and `su` outputs `su: Authentication failure`

I have no idea what may have caused this, this is the first time I'm running these commands since I'm following a Linux course.

Edit: Output of `getent passwd root` is `root:x:0:0:root:/root:5.8`

**Solution:**

I probably managed to mess up the root default shell when trying a `chsh` command.

Edited the first line in /etc/passwd, which is the root entry:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:5.8
```

to

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

The commands now work for me. Lesson learned!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Can you add the output of `getent passwd root`, please?

Comment: yeah it sounds like you somehow have managed to set `5.8` as root's login shell

Comment: then you should be able to do `sudo -s /bin/bash` or `-s /bin/bash --norc` to skip /etc/bash.bashrc, ~/.bashrc

Comment: Sorry for unclear title. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: added getend output in question @NonnyMoose

Comment: This is solved now. Thank you for leading me to the solution!